# My blender animation is wrong in unity3d

Tags: bones, unity

I'm trying to make a paper plane animation controlled by bones.Everything is OK when I play the animation in blender's timeline.But when I export it to unity3d, animations are going wrong.
I don't know how to revise.
You can download the source file to have a look. Or i can send it to your emails.
ps.my english is real bad...just don't mind it,thx!!

[enter link description here](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1boBMvM3)

Comment: Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload files.